# Jquery which object to use

Tags: jquery

I have jquery code like this:

```
$(".element").live('click', function(e) {
    $(".element").css("height",  $(this).parent().height() +"px") ;
});
```

What i want is:

Change the height of all ".element"s to the height of their parent (different for each one). The problem is, that the $(this) tag refers to the element that has been clicked on (dummy test function, will change later). I tried using  $(".element").parent().height(), but this seems not to be right either. How do i refer to correct actual element?

Comment: So on click of any element you want it to have it's height be the parent's height?  Or you want all of them to snap to their parent's height?

Comment: all elements should change their height to the height of the parent (might be different for each one)

Comment: ok, wait a sec.  This is now even more unclear to me.  When ONE `$('.element')` is clicked, you want to change ALL of the `$('.element')`s to their parent's height?  Or you want to just change the single element's parent when it's clicked?

Comment: like written thats just a dummy trigger. Will get executed on something else later. But everything is solved with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean that clicking one `.element` should change the height of all `.element`s to the height of their respective parent, try this:

```
$(".element").live('click', function(e) {
    $(".element").each(function(){
        $(this).css("height",  $(this).parent().height() +"px");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should have no trouble if you do it like this:

```
$(".element").live('click', function(e) {
    $(this).css("height",  $(this).parent().height() +"px") ;
});
```

You're right that `$(this)` refers to the element that was clicked on, so you have to use `this` in all cases.  You want to change the element that was clicked on's height ( this's height ) to the element that was clicked on's parent height ( this's parent height ), right?

Comment: That will only change one of the divs, I think the OP wants all of them to change at once.

Comment: @justkt I think you're right.  But his wording was a little unclear, I asked for clarification.

Comment: this is definitely correct if it's snap the clicked item only to parent height on click

Answer (score 1):

The following code will, on the click on *any* DOM object with the class element, iterate through *all* elements and snap them to parent height.

```
$(".element").live('click', function(e) {
    // go through each object with class element
    $(".element").each(function() {
        $(this).css("height",  $(this).parent().height() +"px") ;
    });
});
```